# Partial Constraint of Low Rank Matrix

Tags: matrices, na.numerical-analysis, matrix-analysis, approximation-theory

Suppose $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a rank $r$ matrix. Let $\Omega$ be a generic subset of $\in \{1, \ldots, m\} \times \{1, \ldots, n\}$ of cardinality $r(m + n - r)$. Denote by $X_{\Omega}$ the matrix that is equal to $X$ on $\Omega$, and 0 on $\Omega^\complement$. Putting it mathematically,
$$X_{\Omega}(i, j) = 
\begin{cases}
X(i, j), \quad & (i, j) \in \Omega\\
0, \quad & (i, j) \notin \Omega
\end{cases}$$

Then, I was wondering that could we prove that
$$\|X - Y\|_{\mathrm{F}} \lesssim \|X_{\Omega} - Y_{\Omega}\|_{\mathrm{F}}$$ 
for any rank $r$ matrices $X$ and $Y$. Any comments related and literature are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**. Try with $2\times 2$ diagonals!

However, the opposite direction does hold true, because $X_{\Omega}$ is a projection  of $X$, so treating $X$ and $Y$ as vectors, and using non-expansivity of projections, we obtain that
\begin{equation*}
  \|P_\Omega(X)-P_\Omega(Y)\| = \|X_\Omega-Y_\Omega\| \le \|X-Y\|,
\end{equation*}
where $P_\Omega$ is the projection onto the indices given by $\Omega$.

Presumably, you are looking for a reverse inequality with some constants? But as you can easily construct, we may have that $X_\Omega=Y_\Omega$ but $X \neq Y$, in which case the inequality you postulate cannot hold with a nonzero constant factor.